# Using the を particle correctly

Tags: particles, particle-を

Im reading up again on how particles should be used properly in Japanese.

Writing this sentence: 「私の車を壊れてです。」I am trying to say, "my car is broken."

Now, using the guide in the link given [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/verbparticles) it states:

> The 「を」 character is attached to the end of a word to signify that that word is the direct object of the verb.

If that is the absolute truth then that means that my sentence given previously 私の車を壊れてです。」is incorrect as the を particle only works on direct objects of a verb, in this case I do not have a verb, rather I have an adjective: 壊れて (Broken).

Am I correct in thinking that the proper way of writing this sentence has to use either:

- The は particle「私の車は壊れてです。」
  OR
- The が particle「私の車が壊れてです。」

In place of を in order for the sentence to be correct? I'm still learning about proper particle use, so any guidance on the limitations of the を particle would be super useful here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

壊れて is not an adjective but the te-form of the intransitive verb 壊れる ("to get out of order", "to break (down)"). This means it's never followed by です. An intransitive verb does not take を. 私の車 is the subject, not the object, of the sentence.

The correct Japanese sentence is:

> 私の車は壊れています。
>   My car is broken. (literally "My car has broken down.")

If you don't know about ている form, please see: [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was also hoping to find out a bit more about the を particle and the accuracy of the quote I gave in my question though.

Comment: @MasterYoda That quote is basically correct, although you'll encounter some exceptions later. Anyway, there is no direct object in your sentence in the first place.